# how to convert a mp4 file to mpg with audio codec ac3 using ffmpeg command

Tags: ffmpeg

I have an mp4 file and i want to convert to mpg with  ac3 audio codec.

i tried:

```
                  ffmpeg -i input.mp4  -c:a ac3 output.mpg
```

the command output:

```
      bash$ ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:a ac3  output.mpg
      ffmpeg version 2.1.3 Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
        built on Jan 15 2014 20:53:51 with gcc 4.8.2 (GCC) 20131219 (prerelease)
        configuration: --prefix=/usr --disable-debug --disable-static --enable-avresample --enable-dxva2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore_amrnb --enable-libopencore_amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libv4l2 --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-pic --enable-postproc --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-shared --enable-swresample --enable-vdpau --enable-version3 --enable-x11grab
        libavutil      52. 48.101 / 52. 48.101
        libavcodec     55. 39.101 / 55. 39.101
        libavformat    55. 19.104 / 55. 19.104
        libavdevice    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
        libavfilter     3. 90.100 /  3. 90.100
        libavresample   1.  1.  0 /  1.  1.  0
        libswscale      2.  5.101 /  2.  5.101
        libswresample   0. 17.104 /  0. 17.104
        libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
      Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from './input.mp4':
        Metadata:
          major_brand     : isom
          minor_version   : 512
          compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
          creation_time   : 1970-01-01 00:00:00
          encoder         : Lavf52.43.0
        Duration: 00:08:41.86, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 437 kb/s
          Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 512x272 [SAR 215:213 DAR 6880:3621], 358 kb/s, SAR 129:128 DAR 129:68, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 2997 tbn, 47.95 tbc (default)
          Metadata:
        creation_time   : 1970-01-01 00:00:00
        handler_name    : VideoHandler
          Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 22050 Hz, stereo, fltp, 75 kb/s (default)
          Metadata:
        creation_time   : 1970-01-01 00:00:00
        handler_name    : SoundHandler
      [mpeg @ 0x9361f60] VBV buffer size not set, muxing may fail
      Output #0, mpeg, to './output.mpg':
        Metadata:
          major_brand     : isom
          minor_version   : 512
          compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
          encoder         : Lavf55.19.104
          Stream #0:0(und): Video: mpeg1video, yuv420p, 512x272 [SAR 129:128 DAR 129:68], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 90k tbn, 23.98 tbc (default)
          Metadata:
        creation_time   : 1970-01-01 00:00:00
        handler_name    : VideoHandler
          Stream #0:1(und): Audio: ac3, 22050 Hz, stereo, fltp, 192 kb/s (default)
          Metadata:
        creation_time   : 1970-01-01 00:00:00
        handler_name    : SoundHandler
      Stream mapping:
        Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 -> mpeg1video)
        Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac -> ac3)
      Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
      frame=12170 fps=343 q=21.2 size=   24850kB time=00:08:27.57 bitrate= 401.1kbits/s
```

the command runs without any error. But when in open the file there is no audio. it only shows video. But the mp4 file plays with audio and video.

Is there any thing i am missing while converting to ac3 audio codec.

```
bash$ mplayer output.mpg
      MPlayer SVN-r36498-snapshot-4.8.2 (C) 2000-2013 MPlayer Team
      206 audio & 433 video codecs
      mplayer: could not connect to socket
      mplayer: No such file or directory
      Failed to open LIRC support. You will not be able to use your remote control.

      Playing  output.mpg.
      libavformat version 55.19.104 (internal)
      MPEG-PS file format detected.
      MPEG: No audio stream found -> no sound.
      VIDEO:  MPEG1  512x272  (aspect 1)  23.976 fps    0.0 kbps ( 0.0 kbyte/s)
      Load subtitles in ./
      Opening video filter: [expand osd=1 aspect=16/9 round=16]
      Expand: -1 x -1, -1 ; -1, osd: 1, aspect: 1.777778, round: 16
      ==========================================================================
      Opening video decoder: [ffmpeg] FFmpeg's libavcodec codec family
      libavcodec version 55.39.100 (internal)
      Selected video codec: [ffmpeg1] vfm: ffmpeg (FFmpeg MPEG-1)
      ==========================================================================
      Audio: no sound
      Starting playback...
      [VD_FFMPEG] Trying pixfmt=0.
      [VD_FFMPEG] XVMC-accelerated MPEG-2.
      The selected video_out device is incompatible with this codec.
      Try appending the scale filter to your filter list,
      e.g. -vf spp,scale instead of -vf spp.
      [VD_FFMPEG] Trying pixfmt=1.
      [VD_FFMPEG] XVMC-accelerated MPEG-2.
      The selected video_out device is incompatible with this codec.
      Try appending the scale filter to your filter list,
      e.g. -vf spp,scale instead of -vf spp.
      [VD_FFMPEG] Trying pixfmt=3.
      [VD_FFMPEG] XVMC-accelerated MPEG-2.
      The selected video_out device is incompatible with this codec.
      Try appending the scale filter to your filter list,
      e.g. -vf spp,scale instead of -vf spp.
      Movie-Aspect is 1.88:1 - prescaling to correct movie aspect.
      VO: [xv] 512x288 => 512x288 Planar YV12 
      New_Face failed. Maybe the font path is wrong.
      Please supply the text font file (~/.mplayer/subfont.ttf).
      subtitle font: load_sub_face failed.
      New_Face failed. Maybe the font path is wrong.
      Please supply the text font file (~/.mplayer/subfont.ttf).
      subtitle font: load_sub_face failed.
      [mpeg1video @ 0xb75a8d20]ac-tex damaged at 12 0
      [mpeg1video @ 0xb75a8d20]Warning MVs not available
      [mpeg1video @ 0xb75a8d20]concealing 544 DC, 544 AC, 544 MV errors in I frame
```

Comment: Please show the full command line output, not just the command. Why do you need MPG as an output format at all?

Comment: What player(s) did you try? Does it work as expected with `ffplay`?

Comment: I have edited my question with the output of ffmpeg and mplayer

Comment: any answer. or some clue why mplayer is showing no sound track

Comment: Not all players support ac3 in mpeg. Have you tried playing in vlc and ffplay?

Comment: sound plays with ffplay but not with vlc and mplayer

Comment: MPlayer doesn't even find the audio stream – which could be because the MPEG video container does not support AC3 audio (there isn't even any mention of it in ISO/IEC 13818-1). I still don't understand why you want MPEG-1 as video, and MPG as an output container. This is one of the oldest and most inefficient video codecs you could use. Can you explain why you need to convert the video in the first place? What is the goal here? I'm fairly sure that you're just asking the wrong question and we can help you better if you just explain what you *actually* need to accomplish.